# Synchronize Android Device with other one

Tags: android, sqlite

I made a android application which creates a database as the administrator needs,

this database is created inside the Android application by admin choice,

The basic application is digital menu, where admin can create or modify menu and menu items on the device, now more than one device is needed, so how other device update automatically

so lets assume that there is 10 android device, now if admin create database in one device, then how other 9 will automatically synchronized with that master device.

is there any solution of this...

Answer (score 0):

Store the .db file on a server and when the app starts, make a call to the server checking if an update is needed. If db is not up to date, grab latest db and load it.

Comment: i dont want to store as in server, it only resides in the android device